# Hyperledger Fabric - Peer subscribing to multiple channel's

Tags: channel, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to fabric and trying to understand:
1) Can a peer subscribe to more than one channel?
2) If Yes, How does the state database (CouchDB) will reflect the latest transactions, does the CouchDB configured for the peer will have all the transactions from both the channels?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. Each channel is a separate DB in CouchDB. You have to include the channel in every transaction request.
3. Yes.